# accessing a ConcurrentHashMap of Objects that can be ConcurrentHashMaps

Tags: java, templates, object, casting, concurrenthashmap

I'm trying to hold data in one dynamic container for productivity's sake.

I initialize it inside a `class` with

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> allInOne = 
    new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
```

`allInOne.put("total", 0.0);` works without error.

`allInOne.put(account, new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>());` works without error.

`allInOne.get(account).put("total", 0.0);` makes `javac` give:

```
DynamicConcurrentHashMapper.java:162: error: cannot find symbol
        allInOne.get(account).put("total", 0.0);
                              ^
symbol:   method put(String,double)
location: class Object
```

I've seen [How do I access nested HashMaps in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774608/accessing-nested-hashmaps-in-java), and I'm happy to have a solution, but is there any way to do it without casting?  If not, is there a better way to template `allInOne`?

---

**Special Case**

I agree with all that this is bad practice for strict atomicity and recommend against it to others, but I'm trying to get a working prototype done as soon as possible.

Comment: Don't do that; it's a bad idea.  And it's also extremely difficult to make it properly thread-safe.

Comment: @SLaks Thank-you!  Yes, I know it's bad practice, but I'd like to have a working prototype now and clean it up later.  Can you offer a suggestion?  Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to explicitly cast the `allInOne.get(account)` to `ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>()`

do like this.

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> accountMap = (ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>)allInOne.get(account);
```

Comment: Is `accountMap` a "pointer" of sorts?  Will altering `accountMap` change the data it is initialized to?

Comment: @Gracchus yes In java all are references except primitive datatypes if you change the reference values it will hit back.

Comment: Wonderful!  That is an excellent workaround!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Its a really bad idea which you are tying to do. But you can do as below.

```
private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>> allInOne = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>>();
```

In this case below line will fail.

```
allInOne.put("total", 0.0);
```

But these two lines compile

```
allInOne.put("", new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>());
allInOne.get("").put("total", 0.0);
```

Comment: Thank-you!  Yes, strict templating won't work in my case.  Can you think of an alternative that doesn't involve templating and casting?  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus this is better solution than my answer.

Comment: No I don't. Do you have any valid reasons not using Generics or Casting?

Comment: @Jayamohan Speed of coding.  I just want a working prototype for a loose proof of concept of sorts.  Once I'm finished with that, I will definitely rework the code to the best practices all here recommend.