# A hashmap inside of a hasmap print out

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I am trying to print out a hashmap that contains A character as the key and the value as another hashmap with Integer and Double 
I have this so far but isn't working.

```
HashMap<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> MapInsideOfAMap = calc.MapInAMap(abc);
    for (Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> outer : MapInsideOfAMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Char: " + outer.getKey() + "\n");
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double> inner : MapInsideOfAMap.getValue().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("int = " + inner.getKey() + ", double = " + inner.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `MapInsideOfAMap`, why you have `Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double>>` (Double) in outer loop and `Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>` (Integer) in inner one?

Comment: There is no map method called `getValue()`. Change it to `get(outer.getKey())`. Also you suddenly switch from `<Integer, Double>` to `<Integer, Integer>` with your inner map. You need to be consistent.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774608/how-do-i-access-nested-hashmaps-in-java/2774626 check

Comment: I've updated the code, sorry about the inconsistencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be like this,

```
for (Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> outer : MapInsideOfAMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Char: " + outer.getKey() + "\n");
        for (Entry<Integer, Double> inner : MapInsideOfAMap.get(outer.getKey()).entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("int = " + inner.getKey() + ", double = " + inner.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Okay, I understood what you were trying to do,
since you already got Outer map entry, you don't have to again use outer map reference, you can directly do like this,

```
for (Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> outer : MapInsideOfAMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Char: " + outer.getKey() + "\n");

        for (Entry<Integer, Double> inner : outer.getValue().entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("int = " + inner.getKey() + ", double = " + inner.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Valid soultion. but in my opionion you should avoid using ``MapInsideOfAMap.get(outer.getKey()).entrySet()`` ervery iteration. even if its O(1). But +1

Comment: @osanger yeah, correct, I was only trying to fix the error, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume your map looks like this:

```
Map <Character, Map<Integer, Double>> MapInsideOfAMap = new HashMap();
```

then you can print your map like this:

```
for (Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> outer : MapInsideOfAMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Char: " + outer.getKey() + "\n");
    HashMap<Integer, Double> innermap = MapInsideOfAMap.get(outer.getKey());
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> innerEntry : innermap.entrySet()) {
         System.out.println("int = " + innerEntry.getKey() + ", double = " + innerEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need just to see map key/values, use `System.out.println`

Map `AbstractMap.toString` knows how to print itself in a nice and readable way.

```
Map<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('A', new HashMap<>());
map.get('A').put(1, 0.01);
map.put('B', new HashMap<>());
map.get('B').put(2, 0.02);
System.out.println(map);
```

prints out this :

```
{A={1=0.01}, B={2=0.02}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second for-loop, you need to access the Map you get as a value from the outer loop. 
You also need to change the type of the Entry in the second loop.

Try this code:

```
for (Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> outer : MapInsideOfAMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key: " + outer.getKey() + "\n");
    for (Entry<Integer, Double> inner : outer.getValue().entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + inner.getKey() + ", Value = " + inner.getValue());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But the complexity of the structure is probably redundant.

```
public static void print(char keyData, Map<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> fromData) {
    System.out.println("print: " + get(keyData, fromData));
}

public static Map<Integer, Double> get(char keyData, Map<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> fromData) {

    for (Map.Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> entry : fromData.entrySet()) {

        Character key = entry.getKey();

        if(key.equals(keyData))
            return entry.getValue();

    }

    return Collections.emptyMap();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply print out the whole map of maps:

```
System.out.println(mapInsideOfAMap);
```

Now, if you want to iterate your outer and inner maps and print their key/value pairs you could use the [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) method:

```
mapInsideOfAMap.forEach((outerKey, outerValue) -> {
    System.out.println("Char: " + outerKey + "\n");
    outerValue.forEach((innerKey, innerValue) -> 
        System.out.println("int = " + innerKey + ", double = " + innerValue));
});
```

Comment: Used Java8 Lambda expression

Comment: @Pankaj Yes, `Map.forEach` expects a `BiConsumer` that receives the key and the value, and this `BiConsumer` can be the target of a lambda expression to make the code more succint.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String z[]) {

    Map<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> MapInsideOfAMap = getmapOfMap();
    for (Entry<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> outer : MapInsideOfAMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Char: " + outer.getKey() + "\n");

        Map<Integer, Double> mapInner = MapInsideOfAMap.get(outer.getKey());
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Double> inner : mapInner.entrySet()) {
             System.out.println(inner.getKey() +":"+ mapInner.get(inner.getKey()));
        }
    }
}

private static Map getmapOfMap() {
    char[] chArr = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k'};
    HashMap<Character, Map<Integer, Double>> mapInsideOfAMap = new HashMap<Character, Map<Integer, Double>>();

    for(char ch:chArr) {
        mapInsideOfAMap.put(ch, getInnterMap());

    }
    return mapInsideOfAMap;
}

private static Map getInnterMap() {
     Map<Integer, Double> map = new HashMap<>();

     for(int i=1000;i<1010;i++) {
         map.put(i, new Double(String.valueOf(i)));
     }
     return map;
}
```